# What is the best way to return number and string from shell function?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have used 'return' to return number from shell function,
Also I know 'echo' is used to return string from function.

**1. return number from shell function**

```
function test1()
{
#some handling
return 0
}
```

**2. return string from shell function**

```
function test2()
{
# some handling
echo "$data"
}
```

I have a case where I need to return both number and string from shell function.

**3. return number and string from shell function**

```
dummy algorithm

function validate()
{
var=$2
if var==something
    return 1
else
    # get modified varible
    modifiedvar=call(var)
    return 0 modifiedvar
}
validate "string"
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Would it be an option to place the results in global variables of the script that you modify in your function?

Comment: `return` is not used to "return" a number but [to exit a function with an exit code](https://ss64.com/bash/return.html).

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408543/how-can-a-bash-function-return-multiple-values

Comment: @JeffSchaller given link is not related to my question

Comment: And would you mind to explain why? You want to return two results, the linked question is about "multiple" results. Note that "number and string" is actually irrelevant, as shell variables are untyped (save for array variables, which are arrays of untyped variables).

Comment: @AdminBee I have a case where I am passing string to shell function and inside function, I am doing some validation...after validation I would like to return 1 in case if vlaidation fails and return 0 and modified string on success case.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you capture the modified string, i.e. how would you call `test2` in your shell script? I ask because your use case would allow you to simply combine both your approaches.

Comment: Since it would appear that you are new to shell scripting, I would recommend you to read  [GrayCat and Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for more information on variable handling and functions in shell scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the string with command substitution, and capture the "number" with the return status:

```bsh
f() {
  echo "Don't panic"
  return 42
}

result=$(f)
status=$?

echo "The function returned >$result< and $status"
```

```
The function returned >Don't panic< and 42
```

Bear in mind that the return status is a number between 0 and 255:

```bsh
$ f() { echo "$1"; return $2; }
$ result=$(f "big number" 300); status=$?
# ........................^^^
$ echo "The function returned '$result' and $status"
The function returned 'big number' and 44
# .....................................^^
$ result=$(f "small number" -300); status=$?
# ..........................^^^^
$ echo "The function returned '$result' and $status"
The function returned 'small number' and 212
# .......................................^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this you're looking for?

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$1"

function f() {
  if [[ -z "$var" || "$var" = "error" ]]; then
    return 1
  else
    var="bar"
    return 0
  fi
}

if f; then
  echo "function returned $?"
  echo "$var OK"
else
  echo "function returned $?"
  echo "error"
fi
```

---

```
$ ./script
function returned 1
error
$ ./script "error"
function returned 1
error
$ ./script "foo"
function returned 0
bar OK
```